# difference between bearing calculation methods

Tags: python, math, geolocation, bearing

I want to able to determine the angle between two geolocations using python. To able to make it happen I considered [movable-type](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) website. When made a lookup for  point1(42.386391,-71.019037) and point2(42.387728, -71.016153) on this website I got 57 degrees which totally makes sense in google maps as well.

So I have converted the formula which is shared on the website to python.
This is the formula on the website:
[image]

And this is my python code:

```
def bearing1(lat1, long1, lat2, long2):
    cal = math.atan2(np.sin(long2-long1)*np.cos(lat2), np.cos(lat1)*np.sin(lat2)-np.sin(lat1)*np.cos(lat2)*np.cos(long2-long1))
    bearing = np.degrees(cal)
    return (360+bearing) % 360
```

But when I run this function I got the angle as 357 degrees.

If you think the red point is point1, and the pink point is point2, the 57-degree angle is so much more sense than 357-degree. (the green X is angle that I want to learn).

[image]

Also, I gave a try for the same values on [this website](https://planetcalc.com/7042/), it is 59 degrees again which is not bad. Obviously, I'm missing something in my code. So do you think what am I doing wrong? What should be changed?

Comment: lat1 etc have tp be in radians. Are they?

Comment: yes it is @dmuir

Answer (score 0):

I'd be carefull about that np.sin(long2-long1) = - np.sin(long1-long2) that might put a minus somewhere in the computation of arctan(x/y) with np.atan2(x,y)

Not sure your problem comes from there though..

Not sure I understand the problem actually ! You want to compute the angle between the tangent to the earth at some point along the direction towards another point by going straight ahead (like under ground) ?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough. I have added a screenshot maybe it helps to describe to my question. Basically I want to learn facing direction. In my calculation, I find 357 but as you can see it is not definitely 357 or something, it is closer to be around 50. I made a few more tests on I got the same issue, my script is giving totally different outputs.  So any ideas could be helpful about this subject. (If Im not clear enough pls let me know)

Comment: Yes, I have played with various math functions and minus statement. (also tried as you said), but still no changes unfortunately   @Thibault Cimic

Comment: Well I think the website you've shown are doing more complicated stuff by taking into account the rondness of the earth, not working on a 2D surface

On 2D surface it would be easier :

Translate p1 to the origin and say p1(0,0) and p2(x2=42.387728-42.386391,-x1=71.016153-(-71.019037)), than tan(teta)=x2/y2 and teta = atan(x2/y2)

And I get 25° :

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=atan%28%2842.387728-42.386391%29%2F%28-71.016153%2B71.019037%29%29

Why do you say it's close to 50 ?

Comment: because if you see screenshot, we can say that it is roughly between 30 and 90 degrees, definitely not 350 degrees. I tested the calculation for a few more locations, when I was expecting to see around 200-270, I  got 45 degrees, so probably this is not we are looking for.

Comment: "The drawing is not a proof" - every teacher in the world :D

I'm pretty sure Google maps shows the surface of the earth with a certain angle so that you get a vision "from above" like if you were a bird or something, and this could twist with the way we sence the angle on a screenshot

Comment: Yes, you are right. But https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html and https://planetcalc.com/7042/   websites give me exactly what I want to have every time. Even if these websites are wrong, I don't care :) I want to have their method. Because those show me what I need to see. So I can change my question like:  how can I have the same results with those websites? :)